# JQuery Validate and Chosen issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

I have a problem with jQuery Validate plugin when using it with Chosen. I dont know why but in order to validate a select box / chosen select I need to add `ignore: ':hidden:not(.chosen)',` into my validator options. However I do have some sections where my select box / chosen select is hidden due to certain options on the form being selected.

Apart from removing the `data-rule-required="true"` from the select with javascript is there any other work around for this?

Comment: There are quite a few workarounds for this.  [Please show all relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

In the script that you use to show or hide your Chosen elements, add/remove another class to the select tag (or whatever underlying tag you are applying Chosen to) that you can then use to filter the validation like this `ignore: ':hidden:not(.validate-me)',`

Comment: Couldn't get it to work for me. I ended up disabling the selects and enableing them instead